# Success callback function is not called

Tags: backbone.js

I`m building a simple backbone application, and have a problem with success callback function in my View.
Here is a code

```
    var EditUser = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
        render: function(option){
            var that = this;
            if(option.id){
                that.user = new User({id : option.id});
                that.user.fetch({
                    success:function(user){
                        var template = _.template($("#edit-user-template").html());
                        that.$el.html(template({user: user}));
                    }
                });
            }else{
                var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html());
                that.$el.html(template({user: null}));
            }
        },
        events:{
            'submit .edit-user-form': 'saveUser',
            'click .delete': 'deleteUser'
        },
        saveUser: function(ev){
            var userDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
            var user = new User();
            user.save(userDetails,{success: function(){
                router.navigate('',{trigger:true});
            },
            error: function(e){console.log(e);}
            });
            return false;
        },
        deleteUser:function(ev){
            this.user.destroy({
                success: function(){
                    router.navigate('',{trigger:true});
                }
            })
            return false;
        },
        wait:true
    });
```

On the SaveUser function,query send to the server correct, but after this, success callback function is not called, for navigating to the app home page.
The same problem appear with deleteUser method.
Any ideas what is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: This is not enough information. We have no idea what user.save() does.

Comment: @pmandell it's a Backbone.js model, so save() uses a POST to the URL associated with the model.

Comment: @volodymyr3131 Is the "error" method being called?  seems like one of that or success should be.   Can you watch this network transaction happen in a browser's debug Net panel (hit F12 in Chrome) and see that the response code is 200ish?  Or you could just put an alert in the success and error methods, to see which is being called.

Comment: @BillJames No, error method is not been called. As for received status, server return 200. I write console.log(1) in both statuses, and seems like none of them is called.

Comment: @BillJames where in his code does it reveal that? I know what Backbone.Model.save() does :D

Comment: Here is my Model, associated with the View:
`        var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
            urlRoot: '/www/Backbone/users.php'
        });
`
But , I thought it wouldn't be nessesarry to post it, because here there is only urlRoot definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be related to the response type from your server, the expected response is a JSON object that will be set on your attributes, but if the response is different as "text" for example, the parse fails.

Here is a fiddle for demo using Mock request

https://jsfiddle.net/gvazq82/rdLmz2L2/1/:

```
$.mockjax({
  url: "hello.php",
  responseTime: 0,
  //responseText: 'A text response from mock ajax'
  responseText: '{"a": "a"}'
});
```

In this example, the error function is been called that is not happening in your case, Is it possible your app defines some default behavior for "Ajax" calls?.

I need more information to be able to determinate this issue, but hope this give you some guidance with your problem.

Comment: Yes! You were correct about response type. I changed it for json , and all my callback functions works! This issue troubled me for many hours! Thank you!